# Use Google Cloud AI Platform - Error message 'Zone doesn't have enough resources available to fulfill request

Tags: zone, gcp-notebook

The answer I read to similar questions doesn't work for me. I am using Google AI Platform notebook and continue to get the following error message for over 24 hours now when  try to start the notebook:
"The zone 'projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/europe-west1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."

Everything worked fine over the last three weeks since yesterday when I received this error. I tried multiple times over the last 24 hours to start the notebook. Always the same error message.
I don't want to recreate the whole notebook as it took me over two working days to upload all data to the instance and for the set-up.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see answers to this issue here in the forum date from 2018 or earlier, so might be outdated.

I found a more recent reply in a different forum:

[error: The zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016898/error-the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request)

Here you will find instructions for [moving to a different zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).

Looks like this is straightforward and does not require you to repeat the set-up.